# after page refresh error "No default engine was specified and no extension was provided" in React js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I installed a Reactjs web application, after connected to the port and `MongoDB` through `bin/www` and `app.js` the navigation is not working, when I click on `about` page it is in the same home page, if I refresh the page I get the following error:

> No default engine was specified and no extension was provided

Below is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "nexg",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

This is my `app.js` code:

```
const express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var logger = require('morgan');
const app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nexgweb_tech', { promiseLibrary: 
require('bluebird') })
//.connect('mongodb://localhost/mern-crud', { useMongoClient: true, 
promiseLibrary: require('bluebird') })
  .then(() =>  console.log('connection succesful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended' :' false' }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
module.exports = app;
```

Below is the `./src/App.js` code:

```Reactjs
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import Services from "./components/Services";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Navigation/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/About" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route exact path="/Services" component={Services} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my `./bin/www` code:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('mean-app:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3005');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

After `npm run build` build folder with some files are generated, after that, I run the command `npm start`. The application is running in port but after clicking on another page and clicked on refresh I get the error.

When I change the start in `package.json` from `script start` to `react scripts start`, the navigation works perfectly, even after refresh also no error, but I need to start port and MongoDB before starting the app. That's why I created `./app.js` and `./bin/www`. The app is not working the above issues have come.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add your complete package.json file? are you using react router?

Comment: {
  "name": "nexg",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
yes,R - router

Comment: when i change start in package.json script start into react scripts start the navigation is working perfectly, even after refresh also no error, but i need to start port and mongodb before starting the app thats why i created ./app.js and ./bin/www , then app is not working the above issues have come.

Comment: the below two comments are my ./src/App.js code : import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import Services from "./components/Services";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";

Comment: ./src/App.js code :  class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Navigation/>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/About" component={About} />
              <Route exact path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
              <Route exact path="/Services" component={Services} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

Comment: Please edit your question and add all of these, it's easier to read the question and it's easier to format.

Comment: thanks for your response and please solve this.., i will edit my question now.

Comment: i edited my question....

Comment: please solve this issue.... :-)

Comment: we will help you for your issue, don't worry, but this first step on generating a good example of your case, adding versions of libraries you use, and formatting the code will always help you get a better and faster response.

Comment: i inserted the express version in package.json, that only i did not inserted earlier. the rest of libraries which i have used are already mentioned in package.json file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually happens when a server's request (Express server) doesn't know how to render the response. Express, [in this line](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3.3.4/lib/view.js#L41), needs to know the extension of the file, or the default view to render the correct response.

With React (in a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)), you don't need to set a default view engine because it will always render your `index.html` (which contains your React app), no matter what url you use, and since you are using React Router, the routing is always handled by `index.html`, and then the router can render the correct route. So what you need to do is to respond with the correct file and extension.

In your `./bin/www` try adding this:

```
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile( 'YOUR INDEX.HTML PATH FILE HERE' );
});
```

After this line:

```
app.listen(port);
```

You have to change `'YOUR INDEX.HTML PATH FILE HERE'` for whatever the path for your `index.html` file is.

If `index.html` is found here:

```
__dirname + '/build/index.html'
```

Then you can set it like this:

```
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build/index.html'));
});
```

If it doesn't work, you can try to add it before:

```
app.listen(port);
```

**connect-history-api-fallback**

You can use the [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) middleware to always fallback to index.html. This can be used in both dev and prod environments.

Use it like this:

```
const connectHistoryApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended' :' false' }));

app.use(connectHistoryApiFallback({
  verbose: false
}));

// static files and folders must be set after connectHistoryApiFallback
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.listen(app.get('port'), (err) => {
  console.info('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support, and i used the above code but not working, instead of that, i added app.use('/About', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build'))); these lines in app.js file, now it is working....

Comment: @Ganesh the problem with this solution is that you will have to add all your routes to the server. Making the server handle every route by redirecting to the index.html should be the correct approach.

Comment: hi, i used the   app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/build/index.html'));
});    and all pages are working, but when i hit the refresh button i got the error message "No default engine was specified and no extension was provided” in React js" again....

Comment: @Ganesh I edited my answer and added another alternative, try using the package `connect-history-api-fallback`

Comment: wonderful suggestion sir, it is working very good... thank you so much...

Comment: sir, please solve this question also ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118520/how-to-add-user-id-to-his-posts-in-reactjs-mongodb ), i have been trying for the last one week, but i did not get any positive result...

Comment: @Ganesh please mark this as the correct answer, and if it helped you please also upvote it. I will have a look at that question as well

Comment: sir, i clicked on tick mark and upvote, but when i click upvote, "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score" this message is showing... , sir, please solve my second question also.... :-) this is my honorable request......

Comment: @Ganesh thank you, don't worry about that. I was looking at that question, but it was closed because it's too broad... this means that your issue is not very specific and it's not clear. Try to create a new question where you only add the relevant code, so that we can work on a specific issue.

Comment: sir , i need your support to this, i created new question , this is the link { https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205918/how-to-insert-user-id-along-with-his-posts-while-posting-after-login-in-reactj } please solve this also sir... :-)