# how to insert user id along with his posts while posting (after login) in reactjs mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

i created user login with fetching all posted books in reactjs and mongodb (MERN), but i want to insert user id with his every post in reactjs mongodb, then only he can see his posts in his own admin panel. below are the code perticulars.
i tried a lot but i got negative, please solve this issue anybody....
thank in advance...

this is my ./app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var book = require('./routes/book');
var auth = require('./routes/auth');
var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/admin_c', { promiseLibrary: require('bluebird') })
//.connect('mongodb://localhost/mern-crud', { useMongoClient: true, promiseLibrary: require('bluebird') })
  .then(() =>  console.log('connection succesful and port runing on 1004'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));


const connectHistoryApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');



app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'false'}));

app.use(connectHistoryApiFallback({
verbose: false
 })); 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.use('/api/book', book);
app.use('/api/auth', auth);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is my ./src/index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
//import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Register from './components/Register';
import Edit from './components/Edit';
import Create from './components/Create';
import Show from './components/Show';
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        <Route path='/Create' component={Create} />
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/register' component={Register} />
        <Route path='/Show/:id' component={Show} />
      </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

This is my ./src/components/Login.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Login.css';

class Login extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      message: ''
    };
  }
  onChange = (e) => {
    const state = this.state
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { username, password } = this.state;

    axios.post('/api/auth/login', { username, password })
      .then((result) => {
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', result.data.token);
        this.setState({ message: '' });
        this.props.history.push('/')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if(error.response.status === 401) {
          this.setState({ message: 'Login failed. Username or password not match' });
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { username, password, message } = this.state;
    return (
      <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          {message !== '' &&
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              { message }
            </div>
          }
          <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
          <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="username" value={username} onChange={this.onChange} required/>
          <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" value={password} onChange={this.onChange} required/>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
          <p>
            Not a member? <Link to="/register"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Register here</Link>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

This is my ./routes/auth.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var settings = require('../config/settings');
require('../config/passport')(passport);
var express = require('express');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require("../models/user");

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please pass username and password.'});
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
    });
    // save the user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Username already exists.'});
      }
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.'});
    });
  }
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({
    username: req.body.username
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.status(401).send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
    } else {
      // check if password matches
      user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (isMatch && !err) {
          // if user is found and password is right create a token
          var token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), settings.secret);
          // return the information including token as JSON
          res.json({success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token});
        } else {
          res.status(401).send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'});
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my ./src/Components/Create.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Create extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isbn: '',
      title: '',
      author: '',
      description: '',
      published_year: '',
      publisher: '',
      newdescription: '',
    };
  }
  
  onChange = (e) => {
    const state = this.state
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { isbn, title, author, description, published_year, publisher, newdescription } = this.state;

    axios.post('/api/book', { isbn, title, author, description, published_year, publisher, newdescription })
      .then((result) => {
        this.props.history.push("/")
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { auth } = this.props;

      var pageTitle = `Welcome, { auth.username }`;
    const { isbn, title, author, description, published_year, publisher, newdescription } = this.state;
    return (
      <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
              ADD BOOK
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h4><Link to="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></span> Book List</Link></h4>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <h1>testtt{ this.state.username }</h1>
                <label for="isbn">ISBN:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="isbn" value={isbn} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="ISBN" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value={title} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Title" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="author">Author:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" value={author} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Author" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description:</label>
                <textArea class="form-control" name="description" onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Description" cols="80" rows="3">{description}</textArea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="published_date">Published Date:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="published_year" value={published_year} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Published Year" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="publisher">Publisher:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="publisher" value={publisher} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Publisher" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="publisher">Newdescription:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newdescription" value={newdescription} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="New Description" />
              </div>
              <input type="submit" name="comment_submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-nexgweb btn-block" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Create;
```

This is my ./routes/book.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Book = require('../models/Book.js');
var passport = require('passport');
require('../config/passport')(passport);

/* GET ALL BOOKS */
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(req, res) {
  var token = getToken(req.headers);
  if (token) {
    Book.find(function (err, books) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(books);
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Unauthorized.'});
  }
});

/* GET SINGLE BOOK BY ID */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Book.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* SAVE BOOK */
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(req, res) {
  var token = getToken(req.headers);
  if (token) {
    Book.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(post);
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Unauthorized.'});
  }
});

getToken = function (headers) {
  if (headers && headers.authorization) {
    var parted = headers.authorization.split(' ');
    if (parted.length === 2) {
      return parted[1];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

module.exports = router;
```

This is my ./models/Book.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  isbn: String,
  title: String,
  author: String,
  description: String,
  published_date: { type: Date },
  publisher: String,
  postedBy: HERE I NEED TO INCLUDE USER_ID,
  updated_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

This is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.6",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5",
    "save": "^2.3.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you have to ref the user id in book schema like

```
var BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  isbn: String,
  title: String,
  author: String,
  description: String,
  published_date: { type: Date },
  publisher: String,
  postedBy:type: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'user'},
  updated_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

like this and insert it into when you posting a book send it through this id through req.body with keyword postedBy your req.body should be like

```
isbn: 'any thing',
  title: 'any thing',
  author: 'any thing',
  description: 'any thing',
  published_date: 'any thing',
  publisher: 'any thing',
  postedBy: 'user._id',
```

. while retrieving it check it user._id is equal to book id like

```
  Book.find({postedBy:req.body.userid(or any other format you want like query params)},function (err, books) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(books);
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'Unauthorized.'});
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your support, i applied the above lines but it is showing {postedBy:type: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'user'}}  syntax error while compiling....

Comment: in ./models/Book.js   i added postedBy:type: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'user'  this line and in ./src/Components/Create.js i edited this section as you said isbn: '',
      title: '',
      author: '',
      description: '',
      published_year: '',
      publisher: '',
      newdescription: '',
      postedBy: 'user._id'    but syntax error in ./model/Book.js showinw while compiling....